# JPA/JPQL insertion & fetch in one

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, auto-increment, jpql

I have a table with an INT primary-key that is autoincremented.

I'm looking to get the value of 
this key-field for the row I just inserted.

I can do that

1) by using [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

or

2) merely querying it by the value I inserted.

However, there "feels" to be a more direct way of retrieving that value.

In (1) above, it is giving me the value on the last inserted row-- not necessarily the one i inserted.

In (2), still there is an extra go-between.

I'm using JPA/JPQL on a MySQL database. JPQL does not have INSERT-- I can only do the insertion 
directly on the EntityManager. So, I can't combine a query to get the field value. I only can do a query on the same transaction as I've done the insertion is on.

Is there a way of getting around this-- getting the value of the key-field on the row yi've just entered?

//=============================

**EDIT**:

I am looking to find out how to get the new, autoincremented key once it is there. I'm aware that the key value is incremented & assigned automatically without me having to do anything. I need that key value, because I have a use for it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

JPA has support for autogenerated identifiers (which BTW, are the recommended strategy). Just annotate your ID field with

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

and JPA will know that the ID is generated by the database, using an auto_increment column, and will get the last inserted ID for you, transparently.